# nodejs discord bot > reading a txt file on change and post the last line

Tags: node.js, discord, readfile

im trying to write a small discord bot which is watching a txt file and post the content, everytime the file changes. it should post only the new line on the txt after its safed. got it working, but with 2 problems

1: the script ist posting only the first content after saving. even if i delete the whole file and enter new content, it post the old ones. if

2: it should post only the new line on change, not the whole file.

whats wrong in my code?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const config = require("./config.json");
const fs = require('fs');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on("ready", function () {
console.log("ready");
});


const content = fs.readFileSync('./test.txt', 'utf8');

fs.watch('test.txt', (eventType, filename) => {
 console.log(content)
  bot.channels.cache.get('783063159983702016').send(content)

});
bot.login(config.BOT_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working now with this

```
fs.watchFile(playlist, (eventType, filename) => {
  fs.readFile(playlist, 'utf-8', (err, data) => {

let lines = data.trim().split("\n")
  console.log(lines[lines.length - 1])
   bot.channels.cache.get('783366173864493117').send(lines)
  });
});
```